# Laravel 6.x - 'create()' record using DataBase DEFAULT values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I've a simple MySQL DataBase table like this:

```
mysql> show create table provenance;
| provenance | CREATE TABLE `provenance` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique incremental id',
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'AUTO-ADDED',
  `instance` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` char(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User name',
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Provenance priority',
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `inserted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2869 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Provenance' |
mysql>
```

As you can see, there are fields with **DEFAULT** value: `name` and `priority`.

Laravel **Model** is something like:

```
class ProvenanceModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'provenance';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'instance',
        'username',
        'priority'
    ];
}
```

and **Controller**:

```
class ProvenanceController extends Controller
{
    public function myStore($array)
    {
        return ProvenanceModel::firstOrCreate(
            [
                'name'          => $array['name'],
                'instance'      => $array['instance'],
                'username'      => $array['username'],
                'priority'      => $array['priority'],
            ]
        );
    } 
}
```

The problem is that the input `$array[]` could not contains `name` or `priority` (they are set from DataBase with **DEFAULT**).

But how I can change my code to avoid an error because, for example, `$array['name']` doesn't exists?

An idea could be to change the **Controller** code to:

```
class ProvenanceController extends Controller
{
    public function myStore($array)
    {
        return ProvenanceModel::firstOrCreate(
            [
                'name'          => $array['name'] ?? 'AUTO-ADDED',
                'instance'      => $array['instance'],
                'username'      => $array['username'],
                'priority'      => $array['priority'] ?? 0,
            ]
        );
    } 
}
```

but If I change the **DEFAULT** on DB I need to change the PHP code and I do not like this.

Is there a way to use the **DEFAULT** DataBase value If the field is not passed?

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure it is already done automatically if you don't insert anything in Name or Priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @prgrm comment, the solution is to insert into `ProvenanceModel::create()` method, only fields received in input.

For example:

```
class ProvenanceController extends Controller
{
    public function myStore($array)
    {
        isset($array['name']) ? $secondArray['name'] = $array['name'] : null;
        isset($array['instance']) ? $secondArray['instance'] = $array['instance'] : null;
        isset($array['username']) ? $secondArray['username'] = $array['username'] : null;
        isset($array['priority']) ? $secondArray['priority'] = $array['priority'] : null;

        return ProvenanceModel::firstOrCreate($secondArray);
    } 
}
```

then if `$array['name']` is not set the `$secondArray` will be:

```
$secondArray[
    'instance' => '<value>'
    'username' => '<value>'
    'priority' => '<value>'
]
```

and the `name` field will be filled with **DEFAULT** MySQL value, `'AUTO-ADDED'`.

---

To make all in one line and without build a `$secondArray()`:

```
class ProvenanceController extends Controller
{
    public function myStore($array)
    {
        return ProvenanceModel::firstOrCreate(
            [
                isset($array['name']) ? 'name' : 'xx' => $array['name'] ?? null,
                isset($array['instance']) ? 'instance' : 'xx' => $array['instance'] ?? null,
                isset($array['username']) ? 'username' : 'xx' => $array['username'] ?? null,
                isset($array['priority']) ? 'priority' : 'xx' => $array['priority'] ?? null,
            ]
        );
    } 
}
```

then if `$array['name']` is not set it will be:

```
        return ProvenanceModel::firstOrCreate(
            [
                'xx' => null,
                'instance' => <value>,
                'username' => <value>,
                'priority' => <value>,
            ]
        );
```

the `xx` field is not in `$fillable` array and will not be used in `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for Laravel to know what the Database defaults are when it constructs the query.

Your best option is to split `firstOrCreate` into 2 calls:

```
$model = ProvenanceModel::where($attributes)->first();

if (is_null($model)) {
    $model = ProvenanceModel::create([
        ...
        // non-default attributes
        ...
    ]);
}

return $model;
```